# Perform 3D Touch quick action shortcut without opening the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, shortcut

I'd like to execute a quick action shortcut (in the home screen) without the app opening. I know how to perform the quick actions, it's just the app going full screen part that I'd like to skip.

Think a music app where you want to access the 'pause' and 'resume' functions. The whole point in using these shortcuts would be not having to open the app.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Added '3D Touch' to the title.

Comment: We need more details. Are you talking about 3D press? If so, have you search here (and elsewhere) on that? What have you tried? What specific issues are you facing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm referring to the 3D Touch, I think that's the only way to perform 'quick actions' from the home screen. I have set up the quick actions, so the options pop up with the 3D Touch. My actions execute as intended (play, pause). It's just that the app will always open as well. I haven't encountered a 3D Touch quick action of another app where the app won't open so I'm not even sure if this is even possible (though it would be just logical).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my app doesn't use this. Also, I wasn't aware other apps always opened. I was asking mostly for clarity for others to help (if they can). I see you edited the title - you might want to mention in your app that you haven't seen any other app **not** open. (I've always found it helpful to ask requesters of things to "show me a working example" sometimes!) Sincerely - good luck! I hope someone has an working answer for you.